# Can't save json in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I can't save string to `JSON` on device, but in simulator can!

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Warehouse" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSMutableArray *arJson = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil] mutableCopy];

NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:prod.title,@"title",
                                                                   prod.price,@"price",
                                                                   prod.descrip,@"descrip",nil];

[arJson addObject:dic];

NSData * data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arJson options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString * myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[[myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Are u sure the resource path is stay in your app document not some where in your Mac's project folder or sth?

Comment: I think this is what your looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853014/file-write-with-nsbundle-mainbundle-fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change files in you main bundle folder. Check full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10671119/1003065

Comment: Thanks you, error was in url. This is correct:                                       NSString *filePath = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0], @"Warehouse.json"];